# GIFV not always playing video

Tags: imgur

Consider this, “GIFV good”: [http://i.imgur.com/SQXB06O.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/SQXB06O.gifv)

Consider this, “GIFV bad”: [http://i.imgur.com/MHfD9WX.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/MHfD9WX.gifv)

Now both of these are recent uploads; 13 and 15 hours old respectively. However
one plays as a video and one plays as a GIF. You can tell because if you right
click *GIFV good* it says *Pause*, while if you right click *GIFV bad* it says
*View Image*.

I know that *GIFV bad* has a video available:

```
$ wget --spider http://i.imgur.com/MHfD9WX.webm
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 542519 (530K) [video/webm]
```

However if you try [http://i.imgur.com/MHfD9WX.webm](https://i.imgur.com/MHfD9WX.webm) directly, it just redirects
you to the GIFV and plays a GIF.

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Imgur staff](http://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/1198#issuecomment-156798726):

> we surface the original GIF if it's under 2M

---

What I really want from Imgur is for media to behave like YouTube videos:

- Play once
- Replay on click

I was able to accomplish this. First I [stopped GIF looping](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/72c8af0/firefox/prefs.js#L55) in Firefox like
this:

```
image.animation_mode; once
```

Then I created [a bookmarklet](http://github.com/svnpenn/bm/blob/4bf9d2f/replay.js) to do the rest:

```
addEventListener('timeupdate', function(wh) wh.target.loop = 0, 1);
xr = document.querySelectorAll('img, video');
for (ya of xr) {
  zu = ya.style;
  zu.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  if (ya.play) {
    zu.border = 'thick solid violet';
    zu.position = 'relative';
    zu.zIndex = 10;
    if (ya.duration) zu.display = 'block';
    ya.onmouseover = function() this.controls = 1;
    ya.onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.cloneNode(1), this);
      this.src = '';
    };
  }
  else {
    ya.onclick = function() this.src = this.src;
    zu.border = /gif/.test(ya.src) ? 'thick solid green' : 'thick solid peru';
  }
}
```

This stops videos from looping, and will replay media on click.